# How should reply model look like i Django?

Tags: django

I am working on blog project in Django. I have made a Comment system that is working fine. I want to add a reply model can anyone tell me how Reply Class will look like in models.py file?

**Here is my Comment Class **

```
class Comment(models.Model):
user=models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
blog_id=models.IntegerField(default=0)
text=models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.text[0:17]+' .... by '+ self.user.username
```

** I am trying with following code but it is giving errors when I makemigrations**

```
class Reply(models.Model):
comment=models.ForeignKey(Comment,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
text=models.TextField()


def __str__(self):
    return self.text[0:15]
```

Comment: Add error text with traceback

Comment: is `Reply` class defined above `Comment` class?

Comment: No it is defined after Comment Class.

Comment: what error do u get when trying to perform `makemigrations`?